# Powerbuilder 11.5 Run command in Win7 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, powerbuilder

I have been developing an application which uses thermal
printers to print receipts.

Until now the following code (PB 11.5) was working as a
charm:

```
Environment env
GetEnvironment(env)
ls_port= 'LPT1'

ls_command = 'COPY ' + ls_tempfile + ' ' + ls_port

Choose Case env.OSType
    Case windows!
        ls_command = 'command.com /c ' + ls_command
    Case windowsnt!
        ls_command = 'cmd.exe /c "' + ls_command + '"'
    Case else
        ls_command = 'cmd.exe /c "' + ls_command + '"'
End Choose

li_cmd = Run(ls_command,Minimized!)
```

I have just deployed my application to a big customer with
**Win7 64bit PCs** and the command does not fire! I cannot print
at all!
I am in an awkard (to say the least) situation.

Can you help me?

Comment: I know the Run command works in 64-bit Windows. Have you tried running the command from a command prompt to see what happens?

Comment: WHat is the typical value of ls_tempfile? If there is a space in it then the COPY won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was not in the PB Run statement but in a **Net Use** that I had done. Net Use in LPTx, COMx in Win7 64bit has tons of issues concerning privileges, user rights etc. Even the Print Directly to Printer option inside Printer Properties causes rights issues!! Oh God...